# How can I include the Singapore theme headline into the Metropolis theme in LaTeX Beamer?

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=blue!55!green}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor} 

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\usepackage{xspace}

\setitemize{itemsep=10pt,% Change the item separation here
label=\usebeamerfont*{itemize item}% These lines are necessary to restore the bullets to each item
\usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize item}%
\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}%
}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]{}% Number float-like environments
```

I am using the Metropolis theme for Beamer but the following codes give me no heading like in Singapore theme. How do I add a heading so that the audience can see the outline of the presentation in Metropolis?

[image]

[image]

I would like to include the heading showing where I am in the presentation using Metropolis.

Comment: Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the Singapore theme headline, check the file `beamerthemeSingapore.sty` and see which outer theme it loads, because this is where the `headline` gets defined. There we find:

```
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
```

Now let's check `beamerouterthememiniframes` for the definition of the `headline` template, which is called:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{miniframes theme}
```

So the solution is to set the `headline` template accordingly after loading `metropolis` and this can be done through:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}[miniframes theme]

\title{How to use Singapore section headline in metropolis theme?}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\section{SECTION}
\subsection{SUBSECTION}
\frame{Content}
\frame{Content}
\frame{Content}
\subsection{SUBSECTION}
\frame{Content}
\section{SECTION}
\frame{Content}
\frame{Content}
\frame{Content}
\frame{Content}
\section{SECTION}
\subsection{SUBSECTION}
\frame{Content}
\frame{Content}
\frame{Content}
\subsection{SUBSECTION}
\frame{Content}
\end{document}
```

Which results in:
[image]